# No such thing as file locking in Google Chrome Packaged Apps? How do we prevent race condition then?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am using the chrome.filesystem when it dawned upon me that it doesn't have any file locking mechanism available. This is very important for my project because we have multiple systems writing to a file that is shared across the network. I need to be able to lock it just prior to writing to prevent race condition.

For example, I am just trying to increment the value in a text file on 2 systems.
It can be possible that:
A reads the content which is '5'
B reads the content which is '5'
A increments it to '6' and write to the file
B increments it to '6' and write to the file

**It should be:**
A locks the file
A reads the content which is '5'
A increments it to '6' and write to the file
A unlocks the file
B locks the file
B reads the content which is '6'
B increments it to '7' and write to the file
B unlocks the file

Comment: To begin with, are you sure your underlying filesystem / network sharing supports locking?